# Display Data with Xvalues correctly in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

So I Have Two array values namely for X-axis and for Y-axis
as you can see below :

```
//For X-axis
var countArray = ["2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30", "2018-12-30 14:12:30" ...] 

//For Y-axis
var numArray = [1,4,5,3,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,3,5,3,5,4,5,6,4,5,4,5,4,5,,3,5,3,4,4,5,3,5,3,34,5,4,4,5,34,5,3,5,3,3,4,5,2,5,12,5,3,2,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,5,2,3,3,3,32,34,2,1,4,5,3,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,3,5,3,5,4,5,6,4,..]
```

The problem is that I want to plot a Highchart based on the above data, but not able to proceed with my method .

Here you can see the fiddle that I have tried.

https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/urxnpb9L/

I Just want to plot the data for the above data and showing the interval in X-axis label as of 1 second.

Any Help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **startPoint** feature to create this chart and **pointInterval** to 1000 which is equal one second.

```
var numArray = [1,4,5,3,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,3,5,3,5,4,5,6,4,5,4,5,4,5,3,5,3,4,4,5,3,5,3,34,5,4,4,5,34,5,3,5,3,3,4,5,2,5,12,5,3,2,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,5,2,3,3,3,32,34,2,1,4,5,3,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,3,5,3,5,4,5,6,4];


var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2018, 11, 30, 14, 12, 30),
      pointInterval: 1000 // one second = 1000 miliseconds
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: numArray
  }]
});
```

---

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y5Lu4hnm/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointStart

Comment: Don't want to use the startPoint feature. I need to use the exact array values as in the data above.. even if it comes as a string

Comment: I see, but those strings are the same - there is no difference in the second value - if you want to use this data you need to change their second values and set them to the xAxis.categories property. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9ucep0sL/

Comment: but the datapoints and the X axis values are of same length . Can we do something that show all the data?

Comment: Nope. Use startPoint feature or defined each x value.